# NSURLCache and Data Protection

Tags: ios, nsurlcache, data-protection

I am trying to protect sensitive data stored in NSURLCache. My app's files and Core Data sqlite files are set to NSFileProtectionComplete. However, I am unable to change the NSURLCache files data protection level to anything other than NSFileProtectionCompleteUntilFirstUserAuthentication. This leaves any sensitive data in the cache exposed when the device is locked.

I need to have the responses cached so repeated requests return 304 responses to prevent data from being re-processed multiple times when not necessary to do so. Also, I need the cache to be protected at rest when the device is locked.

Does anyone have any suggestions for protecting NSURLCache data?

Comment: Any luck? Facing the same issue...

Comment: I've answered my own question with my solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default `NSURLCache` does not support changing the protection level of its store. I've solved my issue by creating a custom `NSURLCache` subclass that stores URL responses in a custom SQLite database with file protection set to `NSFileProtectionComplete`. This seems to be the only solution next to disabling URL caching.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. Can you share some code? Thanks!